# display sitemap.xml format file on page in react

Tags: reactjs, sitemap

I want to display my website's sitemap.xml on browser page, when my route path is './sitemap'. so i define a new component named "Sitemap", that should render my sitemap.xml that i get it from server. i define a state named "data" in my Sitemap component, that when my response comes from server, i setState that (this.setState({data: res})), now i want to render it on my page, so i wrote:

```
render() {
   return(
     <div> {this.state.data} </div>
```

)
}

but i got this error:
"Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object XMLDocument]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead or wrap the object using createFragment(object) from the React add-ons. Check the render method of `Sitemap`."

Comment: Show your `response` format from server. An example would be better

Comment: my response from server is a document that contains set o URLs, actually all website's urls.